# How can i call function onevery click in javascript it run only once

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
var myValue = parseInt(12);
function fontresize(value){
var getval = parseInt(value);
var chngeval = myValue + getval;
localStorage.setItem("fontset", chngeval);
    document.getElementById("changefont").style.fontSize = chngeval + "px";
}

window.onload = function(){
    var allstorage = localStorage.fontset;

    if(allstorage != undefined || allstorage == ""){
    document.getElementById("changefont").style.fontSize = allstorage + "px";
    }

};

 <button onClick="fontresize('5')">+</button>
```

In is a code for increase font size of my page but problem is that it run only once when the page load I would like to call a function on every click can I do that with java script.

Comment: like this https://jsfiddle.net/Ljd6h9x9/?

Answer (score 1):

You don't update the value of `myValue` inside the function, so whenever the button is clicked, the computed font size will **always** be `12 + 5`.

Update your `fontresize` as follows:

```
function fontresize(value)
{
    var getval = parseInt(value),
        chngeval = myValue = (myValue + getval);

    localStorage.setItem("fontset", chngeval);
    document.getElementById("changefont").style.fontSize = chngeval + "px";
}
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/rgvjwtk7/1/)

---

By the way, the `parseInt()` on your first line is superfluous; `12` is already an integer, so you can just use:

```
var myValue = 12;
```

Comment: how come it works when you refresh the page on *Plunker* http://embed.plnkr.co/vIVrzkFP7fs8ufRs2X7m/ but it doesn't work on *jsFiddle* http://jsfiddle.net/Ljd6h9x9/show/

Comment: @guest271314 You should consider editing your comment, because claiming that jsFiddle does not allow use of `localStorage` is misleading, is all. FWIW, my Chrome Incognito works fine with Local Storage (Chrome 48.0.2564.109).

Comment: @Mi-Creativity The jsFiddle demo in my answer works perfectly? http://jsfiddle.net/rgvjwtk7/show/

Comment: indeed, your fiddle works as it should while mine doesn't even though same code is working correctly on plunker.

Answer (score 0):

[**Plunker**](http://embed.plnkr.co/vIVrzkFP7fs8ufRs2X7m/)

```js
var fontSize = 0;
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
  fontresize(fontSize+=5);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving `chngeval` outside of `fontresize` , using `+=` operator to increment `chngeval` ; also substituting `null` for `undefined` at check of `localStorage`

```
var myValue = 12, chngeval = 0;

function fontresize(value) {
  var getval = parseInt(value);
  chngeval += myValue + getval;
  localStorage.setItem("fontset", chngeval);
  console.log(localStorage.getItem("fontset"))
  document.getElementById("changefont").style.fontSize = chngeval + "px";
}

window.onload = function() {
  var allstorage = localStorage.fontset;

  if (allstorage !== null || allstorage === "") {
    document.getElementById("changefont").style.fontSize = allstorage + "px";
  }

};
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/9eSDtDEvUxhPjqa2h0Z0?p=preview